# Server Sent Events not working without php extension

Tags: php, html, server-sent-events

I'm trying to use server-sent events, with out the use of .php at the end of the call. I altered `.htdocs` to allow extensionless php to be called.

```
// works
var evtSource = new EventSource("ssedemo.php");

// does not work
var evtSource = new EventSource("ssedemo");
```

however `localhost/ssedemo.php` and `localhost/ssedemo` return the same data

Comment: Can you show the .htaccess file you used?

Comment: I used multiviews and mod_rewrite in apache to allow extensionless urls

Comment: Figured it out, multiviews and sse calls dont work correctly when redirecting clean urls. disabled multiviews and use mod_rewrite to redirect

Comment: Makes sense. I'd suggest you self-answer, and show the before and after .htaccess file.  (You can tell your php script to handle HEAD and OPTIONS requests, but that is a complex approach and might not even help with multiviews.)

Answer (score 0):

That's because when you make the request "http://localhost/sse" it is going through your webserver, which is rewriting the request to get sse.php

When you PHP script is including "ssedemo.php", it isn't getting it through the webserver, it is looking for the file locally on the filesystem.

Comment: `code` var evtSource = new EventSource("ssedemo.php");

 this line is in the html, not the php

Comment: Ah, I see now the var evtSource instead of $evtSource! What errors are you getting in firebug? Does it say "ssedemo" is undefined or is there a 404?

Comment: Ahh, the header from the ssedemo call is not correct